# None linear activity transition animation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions

I want to implement a none linear activity transition animation.

My current anime xml file

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

What i want to do is animation to start slow end in faster speed.

Comment: to show animation slowly, increase duration of animation.

Comment: that's not what i want ... i want animation to speed up incrementally...So animation would start slow end in faster speed....I don't know how to describe this better than this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:interpolator` let's you manipulate the rate of change of an animation. If you want to starts out slowly and then accelerate use `AccelerateInterpolator`.

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

Comment: Thanks.This is exactly what i need. I'm guessing we can also code custom interpolators too?

Comment: Thats right. Have a look at [Animation Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html).